# How to build a "conditional sentence" for the next purpose?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I want to ask my friend to call me when when he wakes up (or when he **will** wake up?) today. Now, my question is what kind of [conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences) *(zero, 1st, 2nd, 3rd)* I have to use in such case, if any, or maybe it is not conditional at all when it starts with "when"?

> "When you **wake-up**, please call me"? (present simple)

or

> "When you **will wake-up**, please call me" (future simple)

or

> "When you **are waking-up**, please call me" (present continuous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I am having some trouble understanding what you are asking.

Of the three sentences provided, only the first one would be used. In general, we do not use the ***future tense*** when we start a sentence with "**when**", so the second sentence sounds awkward. Also, one can't make a call while they are actively walking up (they would wake up and then call) so the third sentence sounds weird.

Comment: Thank you. +^ 1. I'd like to understand what wasn't clear in my things, so I can improve it. 2. your claim regarding the 3rd structure makes sense. But it should be the same claim about the 1st one. Maybe it's not correct at all to use when you wake-up in such context and it's better to say right after you (will?) wake up. ?